# Spring JDBC NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jdbc

I'm a first time poster who is a beginner at Spring. I believe I have the basic concept down, however I am running into some errors when I try to write my own code. I did my homework and I looked at other related topics on the site, but I still have not found why my code is not working.

Please forgive me if I made any stupid mistakes. Here are all my relevant snippets of code:

DAO Interface

```
public interface TestDAO {

public int getId();

}
```

Main SQL Connection Code

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;


public class TestDb extends JdbcDaoSupport implements TestDAO{

private SimpleJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public int getId()
{
    String sql="SELECT DOI.DOI_ID FROM ***.DOI where DOI='test58'";
    int id=jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);
    return id;
}

public void createTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

}
```

beans.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

  <bean id="webMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/Form.html">DoiEntry</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="DoiEntry" class="com.****.****.DoiEntry">
    <property name="eventsService" ref="eventsService"/>
    <property name="sendEventsQueueService" ref="sendEventsQueueService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
    <property name="username" value="**USER**" />
    <property name="password" value="**PASSWORD**" />
</bean>

<bean id="testDAO" class="com.****.****.TestDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="testDb" class="com.****.****.TestDb">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

And finally, my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

<display-name>DOILookupApp</display-name>
<description>
    This is a simple web application with a source code organization
    based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
</description>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DOILookup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.****.****.DoiLookup</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DOILookup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DOI</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<taglib>
<taglib-uri>
    functions.tld
</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>
    functions.tld
</taglib-location>
</taglib>

    <!-- The main spring MVC servlet -->
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>beans.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


</web-app>
```

Here's a JSP file I use to view it in a webpage. Disregard the srciptlet, I know they're bad coding practice, I just needed something for testing.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*, java.sql.*;" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Test DB</title>
</head>
  <body>

<jsp:useBean id="testDb" scope="session" class="com.****.****.TestDb"/>

<% 
  int output=testDb.getId();
  out.print("DOI ID for test58 is: ");
  out.print(output);


%>

  </body>
</html>
```

And finally, here is my error message

type Exception report

message

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.****.****.TestDb.getId(TestDb.java:15)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.testDb_jsp._jspService(testDb_jsp.java:78)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I know this is a lot of code to look through, but thank you in advance for all your help.

Tim

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. I changed my code to the getJdbcTemplate() method, however it still does not work. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Are you still getting a NPE? If so, work out what might be null from the stacktrace and check it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess your `jdbcTemplate` is null because it isn't being injected. Your `createTemplate` method won't be called.

You should use the instance that is provided by `JdbcDaoSupport`. Remove the `createTemplate` method and the `jdbcTemplate` instance and replace your `getId` method with:

```
public int getId()
{
    String sql="SELECT DOI.DOI_ID FROM ***.DOI where DOI='test58'";
    int id=getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql);
    return id;
}
```

If you are actually trying to override the parent method, it's called `createJdbcTemplate`.

Alternatively, forget about extending `JdbcDaoSupport` at all as it doesn't really add much. Instead you can inject a `DataSource` directly into your own bean and create the template instance. Using constructor injection:

```
public class TestDb {
    private final JdbcTemplate template;

    public TestDb(DataSource ds) {
        template = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
}
```

and the bean in the app context would look like this:

```
<bean id="testDAO" class="com.****.****.TestDb">
    <constructor-arg  ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JdbcTemplate that is provided by JdbcDaoSupport instead of having your own in a private field. You access it via the getJdbcTemplate() method of JdbcDaoSupport.

Also, you don't access Spring beans using jsp:useBean. Instead you call the bean in your controller (using Spring WebMVC) and send the result to the JSP.

In [this](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-33482.html) forum they talk about a way of accessing beans without Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Change `TestDb.createTemplate(DataSource dataSource)` signature to `TestDb.setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)` and try again. You get NPE because createTemplate method is never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You need this method on your DAO:

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

Since the method you have to create the JdbcTemplate never runs, that's why you get the nullpointer exception.